# Draw hollow circle divided into equal parts

Tags: iphone, ios, uibezierpath

I want draw a hollow circle that look like the below image

[image]

I got the below code snippet to draw hollow circle

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        // Determine our start and stop angles for the arc (in radians)
        startAngle = M_PI * 1.5;
        endAngle = startAngle + (M_PI * 2);

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Display our percentage as a string
    NSString* textContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.percent];

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Create our arc, with the correct angles
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2)
                          radius:130
                      startAngle:startAngle
                        endAngle:(endAngle - startAngle) * (_percent / 100.0) + startAngle
                       clockwise:YES];


    // Set the display for the path, and stroke it
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 50;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [bezierPath stroke];

    // Text Drawing
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake((rect.size.width / 2.0) - 71/2.0, (rect.size.height / 2.0) - 45/2.0, 71, 45);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [textContent drawInRect: textRect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 42.5] lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

I need the separator lines also in the hollow circle,as in the above image.Any suggestion will be helpful ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281811/drawing-circle-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [HKCircularProgressView](https://github.com/Harmek/HKCircularProgressView).
I'm using it for my own project, extending the functionality for your need should be easy.

Comment: I tried the code , It fits best to my need . I found one issue with the code , when I give current value  as < 7 , one block in the circular progress is missing out.I have uploaded screen shot here http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/87da4f50 ... Did you faced same issue ?

Comment: Hm, unfortunately i can't take a look at the screenshot here at my workspace because the firewall is blocking the hosting site. Actually i didn't encounter any major issues with HKCircularProgressView. If you intend to use the code, i'd suggest to repor a issue on HKCircularProgressView's github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering exactly what was asked, but a Simple solution for dividing any circle in three equal parts that solved my purpose-

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2.f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2.f);
CGFloat radius = 8.f;

UIBezierPath *portionPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[portionPath1 moveToPoint:center];
[portionPath1 addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:radians(0) endAngle:radians(120) clockwise:YES];
[portionPath1 closePath];

[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
[portionPath1 fill];

UIBezierPath *portionPath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[portionPath2 moveToPoint:center];
[portionPath2 addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:radians(120) endAngle:radians(240) clockwise:YES];
[portionPath2 closePath];

[[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
[portionPath2 fill];

UIBezierPath *portionPath3 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[portionPath3 moveToPoint:center];
[portionPath3 addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:radians(240) endAngle:radians(360) clockwise:YES];
[portionPath3 closePath];

[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[portionPath3 fill]; }
```

At top put these two lines.

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
static inline float radians(double degrees) { return degrees * PI / 180; }
```

Hope this will help anybody else too. :)